# linking failed when building my own project using LLVM

Tags: project, llvm

I'm learning to build a llvm project, this is the reference: http://llvm.org/docs/Projects.html. I use the "llvm/projects/sample" directory as the primary project skeleton, and it works. Then I want to build tools from "llvm/examples" to my project, such as Fibonacci, it can't work. I do it this way: first copy the "llvm/examples/Fabonacci" directory to "MyProj/tools" ("MyProj" is top level of my project) and change Makefile to contain Fabonacci target, then configure & make. but the Fabonacci tool seems can't be built. It depends on some libs when linking. So what can I do if I want to build the source code from "llvm/projects/example" in my project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide LLVM libraries to linker when building your own project. This means adding some flags, library directories and libraries themselves to link command. Build script probably needs some editing.

[llvm-config](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html) tool can be used for providing necessary options to compiler/linker. Check [documentation and examples](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html).